# Laravel external API password handling

Tags: laravel, security, webapi

I am wiring an laravel web application for a small project.
One of the features is to access the API of a foto database ([piwigo](https://piwigo.org/doc/doku.php?id=dev:webapi:start)).
I am very new to laravel and have 0 experience in web security so I was wondering what is the best way to set it up.

I managed to setup the API access trough laravel by creating a `PiwigoClient` model with a login method, that will pass the response coockies to other request to piwigo:

```php
class PiwigoClient extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public static $apiURL = 'https://not-actual-piwigo-link/ws.php';

    public function login() {
        $response = Http::asForm()
            ->post($this::$apiURL . '?format=json', [
                'method' => 'pwg.session.login',
                'username' => 'UserName',
                'password' => 'PassWord'
        ]);

        return $response;
    }

    public function test() {
        $login = $this->login();
        $cookies = $login->cookies();
        $response = Http::withOptions(['cookies' => $cookies])
            ->get($this::$apiURL, [
                'format' => 'json',
                'method' => 'pwg.tags.getImages',
                'tag_name' => 'ImageTag'
        ]);

        return $response->json();
    }
}
```

Now I was wondering, it does not feel safe to leave the `'PassWord'` like this in the `PiwigoClient` model file. What would be the safest and most convenient way to "store" the password?

Comment: use .env files that is in your project root directory. in your class make a constructor which fetched PassWord from env and set a private variable to api password and then call $this->api_pass on http form. lmk if you want code or smh for this.

Comment: and also never save api keys in class for testing purpose its fine but never upload it to anywhere this may risk exposing your passwords and it's a huge **NO NO**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard practices are to store "secret" keys in `.env` and then reference them in your codebase via a config file.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-config

```
// PiwigoClass
public function login() {
        $response = Http::asForm()
            ->post(config('piwigo.url') . '?format=json', [
                'method' => 'pwg.session.login',
                'username' => config('piwigo.username'),
                'password' => config('piwigo.password')
        ]);

        return $response;
    }

// config file piwigo.php
<?php
return [
'password' => env('PIWIGO_PASSWORD', 'PassWord'),
'username' => env('PIWIGO_USERNAME', 'UserName'),
'url' => env('PIWIGO_URL', 'https://my_api_url...')
]
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if I understand correctly I declare them in my `.env` file. But I don't fully grasp the purpose of the `config/piwigo.php` file.
Is it to make the `'PIWIGO_PASSWORD'` callable as `piwigo.password`? And in `env('PIWIGO_PASSWORD', 'PassWord')` does `'PassWord'` serve as a default orso?

Comment: yeah, the second parameter of the `env()` function is a `default` value if the env-key does not exist.

The purpose of the config file is to not access .`env` values directly and it also works well as a replacement for CONSTANTS being scattered through your codebase. It will also allow you easily switch between different environments and if you're missing a key, the config file could help you to realize that a `.env` variable may be missing. It's just good practice in general.